Travelling as a non-EU citizen while waiting for residence card as family member of a EU citizen
I'm writing because I am having a hard time finding a clear answer. Migratiknsverket in Sweden where we live is not any help at all.
My wife (Turkish citizen) and I (Danish citizen) moved to Malmö, Sweden a few weeks ago. I still work in Denmark, and I am planning on continuing to do so.
I just received my personnummer (Swedish identity number) and we have applied for the same for my wife.
We are also about to apply for a residence card for my wife (as a family member of me as an EU citizen).
My wife's 90 days stay on her Schengen visa (tourist visa for Denmark) will finish in the middle of January, and I know, that the Swedish authorities will be nowhere near done with the application.
So my question is:

Is she allowed to travel within the EU, even though she is 'technically overstaying'? It could be nice, if we were able to visit my family and our friends in Denmark, and her sister in Germany.

Is she allowed to travel outside the EU, for example going to Turkey to visit her family and friends and then come back to Sweden (via Copenhagen Airport) still while 'technically overstaying'?


I hope you can help me, because it's a jungle getting information on this subject.

Did your wife get some sort of certificate attesting that she applied for the residence card? Would you be travelling together?

She will apply online today, I guess she will get a receipt. Yes, we will ve travelling together.

Basically she's allowed to benefit from her derived right of free movement whenever she is traveling with you or to join you.  The document from the Swedish authorities only serves as evidence that she benefits from the right and that she is exercising it by residing with you in Sweden.  She can prove her right of free movement by any other means while she waits for the document.
If the two of you are traveling together then you should not need more than your Danish passport (proving your identity and EU citizenship), her passport (proving her identity) and your marriage certificate (proving your relationship).  In my experience it has never been necessary actually to show a marriage certificate when crossing a border.
To enter the Schengen area, your wife should have a valid visa, but border officers should allow her to enter without one provided she has the evidence described above.  Boarding a flight into the Schengen area will be rather more difficult without a visa, so I would not recommend trying to do so.  If her visa remains valid, however, the fact that she's exceeded the 90-day limit is not relevant when she travels with you and therefore benefits from the derived right of free movement.
